# What is the strongest attack a Pokemon can have?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokemon Go, each Pokemon has an attack and secondary attack that have a variety of different attack power. For the longest time, the highest I've seen was **60**; so I assumed that was the highest. Today I evolved a Raticate that had a **70** Hyperbeam.

What is the strongest attack a Pokemon can have?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In terms of the damage of a single attack the highest are: **Solarbeam** and **Hyperbeam** both at 120. However remember that this damage does not mean it is the best move because both are special attacks that require 100 energy and they have very high delay on the attacks.

If you want to see the moves with the highest DPS (damage per second) checkout this [**Google Spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_nO-IuAWZk3iAtFNDdeG7E_98XBC3DsGW0WPWkiQnuk/htmlview?pref=2&pli=1&sle=true#gid=766735675). DPS is a better measure on which attack is the best. Note that after Niantic's huge damage update, most of the moves are relatively close in terms of DPS, so types matter more than just pure DPS. Also, after this update the special attacks were buffed a lot so they are definitely worth using instead of spamming the standard attack.

---

The best moves for attacking are:

- **Pound** for Standard Attack at 13 DPS with attack speed of 540 ms
- **Stone Edge** for Special Attack at 32 DPS with attack speed of 3100 ms

The best moves for defending are:

- **Bubble** for Standard Attack at 6 DPS
- **Stone Edge** for Special Attack at 20 DPS

---

Credits for the spreadsheet goes to this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v99uo/move_powers_have_been_updated/).

**UPDATE: This post has been updated after Niantic's huge update to the DPS of moves (July 29, 2016).**

Comment: That's weird, I've got a Flareon with Heat Wave 80. Is Heat wave different?

Comment: The move powers have been updated. **[Latest Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_nO-IuAWZk3iAtFNDdeG7E_98XBC3DsGW0WPWkiQnuk/htmlview?sle=true#gid=2131171395)** - More details - *[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4v99uo/move_powers_have_been_updated/)*

Comment: @ShaunakD is correct. My brother just caught a Ponyta with a 100 powered Fire Blast. The current spreadsheet lists Fire Blast as 60 power

Comment: @Wondercricket Niantic recently had a huge update to the damage of almost all moves. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll update this post.

Answer (score 4):

*Psystrike* has 70 power as well as *Hyperbeam*. Both are currently the strongest single target attacks in the game. 

Runner ups are *Thunder* & *Solar Beam* with 65 power each.

PS: There are 11 attack moves with 60 power.

*Source: Protobuf file*